# Calling shell script with multiple input arguments in different directories with find

Tags: shell, find, sh

I'm trying to run a shell script with multiple input arguments which are files found by `find`.

The script looks like this

```
#! /bin/sh

pto_gen "$@" -p 0 -o project.pto
cpfind --multirow -o project.pto project.pto
autooptimiser -a -o project.pto project.pto
pano_modify  --projection=0 --fov=AUTO --center --canvas=100% --output-exposure=0 --straighten --ldr-file=PNG -o project.pto project.pto
hugin_executor --stitching --prefix=pano project.pto
```

My files are in directories like this

```
root --
    dir1
        subdir1 --
            file1.tif
            file2.tif
            file3.tif
            ...
        subdir2 --
            file1.tif
            file2.tif
            file3.tif
        ...
    dir2 --
        subdir1 --
            file1.tif
            file2.tif
            file3.tif
            ...
        subdir2 --
        ...
```

It input arugments are passed to the `pto_gen` fine with I run them using

```
find . -name "*.tif" -exec pano.sh {} +
```

However, that places the result in the directory I launched the script from (e.g `root` instead of `subdir1`, `subdir2`, etc.)  To be clear, each subdirectory should contain the resulting `pano.png` created from the tiffs in that subdirectory.  I read that I could use the following as an alternative

```
find . -name "*.tif" -execdir pano.sh {} +
```

However, this appears to pass the input arguments to the first line of the script one by one. Adding `echo $@` shows the list of files is being passed into the script correctly, but they are getting parsed by the first command differently when using `-exec` vs. `-execdir`.

Any thoughts on the best way to run this script and have the results end up in the appropriate place would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure why this does not work for you. Wild guess: Did you try to change `pto_gen "$@" -p 0 -o project.pto` to `pto_gen -p 0 -o project.pto "$@"` (according to `man pto_gen`). If an argument contains a `-` then `pto_gen` could misinterpret that file as an option. This could also explain the difference between `-exec` and `-execdir`  as the former uses paths starting at `root` and the latter uses paths of the form `./file`. Maybe the leading/missing path components change `pto_gen`'s interpretation of the arguments (option vs. file).

Comment: Tried moving `"$@"` to the end but its still giving me `pto_gen: No valid image files given.` Odd thing is `echo "$@"` produces the file names.

Comment: Can you try `/bin/bash`, instead of `/bin/sh` ?

Comment: tired changing the shabang, calling bash directly `find . -name "*.tif" -execdir bash pano.sh {} +` and switching to bash.  None seem to work.  I'm on MacOS Catalina btw.

Comment: Thank you for trying. It seems like we need even more information to understand what's going on here. Can you boil down your problem to a minimal reproducible example (for instance one subdir with two files) and give us the actual file names?

Comment: @agf1997 : If you do a `echo  invoked at $PWD with: "$@"` at the very sart of `pano.sh`, you will see that `find` indeed passes more than one argument, provided there is more than one matching file name in the directory. You should get as many invocations of pano.sh as there are directories with matching files.

Comment: @Philippe : What difference should it do to run _bash_  with **this** script? This is a simple _sh_  script without bashisms.

Comment: @agf1997 : The title of your question is misleading. I don't see a recursive call anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: @user1934428 how is it not recursive?  The whole point is to start at `root` and apply the script in each folder down the tree where tiff files are found.

Comment: "Recursive" means that a program calls itself. If `pano.sh` would itself contain an invocation of `pano.sh`, it would be recusrive. You just make a tree traversal (of the directory tree). Recursions in shell scripts are rare, BTW, and then usually done by recursive shell functions, not scripts.

Comment: @agf1997 : See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Recursive_programs)  for a definition of _recursion_. While you **could** do a tree traversal using recursion (and `find` is likely using recursion internally, but we would have to see its source code to know this for sure), **you** don't use any recursion in your program.

Comment: @user1934428 idk ... I usually think about it like `cp -r`  That not `cp` calling `cp` is it?

Comment: Maybe it does internally, we don't know, but this is not the point. Still, there is a difference between the concept of _recursively copying_ something and writing a _recursive program_. If your title would say _recursively traversing a directory tree_, this would be a correct usage of the term.

Comment: Can you run manually `pto_gen` in `dir`/subdir1` with multiple files, to see if you get expected result ?

Comment: @Philippe yes `pto_gen *.tif` works

Comment: You mean this works `pto_gen *.tif -p 0 -o project.pto` ? `but they are getting parsed by the first command differently when using -exec vs. -execdir` How do you know that ?

Comment: Yes ... sorry I should have included everything, not just the file part.  Not following "but they are getting parsed by the first command differently ..."

Comment: @agf1997 Did you try my script?

Answer (score 0):

With find, you have no guarantee that the `command` in `-execdir command {} +` will be called only once in each directory.

It is similar to `-exec cmd ;` vs `-exec cmd {} +`, for the + version man page says:

```
The total number of invocations of the command will be much less than
the number of matched files.
```

That is, with `+` the command will be called less times than with `;`. No guarantee that the command will be run only once for all found files.

---

I found this interesting, because its sometimes hard to manipulate with `find`, so I tried to find a solution.

Probably the easiest correct way to solve it would be first finding the directories with `.tif` files, then in each of these directories run another `find` to find the `.tif` files in that directory, and supply the filenames to `xargs`, which as opposed to find, executes the command with all arguments that can fit in:

from `man xargs`:

```
xargs [options] [command [initial-arguments]]

The command line for <command> is built up until it reaches a system-defined limit.
```

This limit should be enough for your case.

I wrote this as a script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
dirs="$(find . -name '*.tif' -printf '%h\n' | sort -u)"

printf '%s\n' "$dirs" |
while IFS= read -r dir ; do
    echo "Processing directory: $dir"
    find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -name '*.tif' -printf '%f\0' | ( cd "$dir" ; xargs -0 -t /path/to/pano.sh )
done
```

Run it from the location where you want to start looking for the directories with `.tif` files.

**EDIT**: I corrected xargs working directory.